# Как в Firewalld от Redhat (Linux) указать правило?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, redhat

имеется задача разрешить доступ к локальному серверу на базе RH с определенного ИП адреса и порта, в Ubuntu это делается так:

```
sudo ufw allow from x.x.x.x to any port 7200
```

в RH (firewalld) как указать данное правило?

Comment: понимаете, какое дело. с правилами netfilter-а — это как в «уловке-22»: если вам действительно надо что-то разрешить, значит вы об этом прекрасно знаете, так как сами же и запретили перед этим. а если вы ничего специально не запрещали, то значит проблема у вас где-то совсем в другом месте, не в программе linux и не в её сетевой подсистеме.

Comment: согласен, а возможно что firewalld после релоада или перезагрузки сервера теряет правила разрешения?

Comment: вот судя по вашему вопросу, вы ничего и не запрещали. соответственно, вам и разрешать нечего, и беспокоиться о «релоаде или перезагрузке» не имеет смысла. // а вот если вдруг действительно что-то запрещали, так просто всё взад верните, и будет вам шчастье.